# Windows Service Configurations in Database

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have few configuration settings for a Windows Service. Those settings are kept on database and expected to be picked up every time the Timer ticks and behave accordingly. The reason is that, User should be able to change those settings from GUI screen and Service should act based on the new settings from database ( without the need of restarting the service)

However the issue is, many times the service is required to be restarted to behave correctly based on the new values in database.

Can anyone help in identifying.. what could be the possible reason? Why the service is not working without being restarted?

Thanks in advance.

~Saroj

Comment: on every Timer tick, do you reload all config from the database ? You can also use a file based config

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your service is developed, but one of the most possible reasons is that some of configurations and settings are loaded into memory as:

- Static class fields.
- Singletons.

In both cases, if the service doesn't rewrite static values, until the service life-cycle ends and it gets initialized again, it won't know about any change in your database.